# What is this just the middle vimgolf challenge doing?

Tags: vim

So in working http://www.vimgolf.com/challenges/54862fbb3f90ac0002904cf5 one solution is:

```
)3:wq!<CR>
```

My vim cheat sheet says:

) is "end sentence".  Not sure how the "3" fits in.

But "wq!" I know as write/quit.

What is this set of keystrokes doing?

Answer (score 7):

**Command**

`)3:wq!<CR>`

**Input**

```
Leave only the
numbered lines.
LINE 1
LINE 2
LINE 3
That's all.
Thank you
very much.
```

**Breakdown**

```
)      goes one sentence forward. This positions the cursor at LINE 1
3      starts a range of 3 lines for the next command. 
:wq!   writes the range to the file. 
       You should notice that when typing :, the range get's set to .,.+2
```

I'm not sure where to place the `:` as it switches from normal mode to command mode so following breakdown is equally valid

```
)      goes one sentence forward. This positions the cursor at LINE 1
3:     starts a range of 3 lines and enters command line mode
wq!    writes the range to the file. 
       You should notice that when typing :, the range get's set to .,.+2
```

Answer (score 3):

- `)` puts the cursor after the current sentence, on `LINE 1`.
- `3:command` is expanded by Vim to `:.,.+2command`, which means "execute `command` on the current line and the two next lines".
- `.,.+2wq!` writes only the given lines to file, effectively removing any other line from the buffer/file.

See `:help range` and `:help :write`.